# Access iOS / Android gallery contents in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

It seems that currently the only possibility to access the Android and iOS gallery is via `CN.openGallery()`, which opens an external application provided by the operating system.

My question is if this is actually the case, or if there is a way to access the gallery contents differently.

For example, to show a container with a list of the gallery photos and videos inside a `Form`, would I need a CN1Lib that is not there yet, or is there any other way?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Historically access to the gallery was very restricted. Newer versions of iOS/Android have better APIs for this access but we didn't get around to expose them yet. We thought about adding some of that to the CameraKit cn1lib but didn't get around to it.